# Google Apps Script - get 'hosting' url for public image on Drive

Tags: image, google-apps-script

and thanks in advance for your help!

I'm trying to get the 'hosting' URL for public images on my Google Drive, with the intent of pulling the images into a spreadsheet using the Image formula.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the hosting URL from Google Apps Script.

The ID used in the hosting URL isn't the same as the ID of the file on Drive, either, so I can't figure out how to build the URL.

Is there a way to get this URL or ID so I can pull in these images to my spreadsheet?

Thanks again for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can the use of [permalink](http://googlesystem.blogspot.fr/2013/02/permalinks-for-google-drive-images.html) be an option for you?
here an exemple:

```
var baseUrl = "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=";
function myFunction() {
  var images = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  while(images.hasNext()){
    var img = images.next();
    // img.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW); this line can be dangerous!!
   var imgId = img.getId(); 
    var pubUrl = baseUrl+imgId; // the public URL
    Logger.log(pubUrl); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just what I was looking for!  Weird that this is different than the hosting link that Google puts on the drive page. Thanks for your help!